# jQuery Mobile footer not fixed when listview dynamically added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

I am dynamically building a list view when a page loads and have my footer set to fixed but it doesn't work when the listview is dynamically added.

How can I fix this?

http://www.blueshoemobile.com/preview/buzzoffbase/categories.html?cat_id=96&cat_title=Restaurants

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set `$.mobile.autoInitializePage` to false in the beginning of your script. After dynamically generating the DOM with the correct roles, call `$.mobile.initializePage()`